# Why are bigger residential electrical panels designated 320/400A?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Panels for bigger homes or homes with higher electrical loads are described as 320/400A. Why the "dual" designation? Which one is it, 320 or 400A that they support?

Answer (score 3):

Structures and RVs follow NEC (National Electrical Code).

Utilities follow NESC (National Electrical **Safety** Code).

In the structure/NEC way of thinking, *continuous loads* put excessive strain on the system, and require a 125% disfavorable derate which is then included in the rating.  For instance a 3800W water heater derates to 125% of that or 4750W, which is *just under* the 4800W of a 240V/20A circuit. So we treat that in all respects as a 20A water heater even though it's really 16A.

So in NEC, a load which is 80A continuous yet 100A intermittent is given the nomenclature of a "100A load".

In the utility/NESC way of thinking, you spec the continuous rating of the thing, and are tolerant of a 125% intermittent overload.  So in their nomenclature, that same 80A continuous/100A intermittent is deemed an 80A load and they're fine with that having a 100A breaker.

So it's a difference in nomenclature and nothing more.

Comment: And that is fine. However when I go buy a 200A panel everybody calls it 200A panel, not 160 (200)A. That is why I had confusion

Comment: @AlessioSangeli Yeah, there aren't a lot of retail shops who sell utility type gear.  They'd only have one customer :)

Answer (score 1):

320 amp continuous

80% of 400 = 320.

https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/320amp-vs-400amp.127202/